# Why I'm getting error including ENet library on MSVS2019

Tags: c++, enet

I wanted to include [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org/) in my VS2019. I included its lib and directories and include its lib in Addition Dependencies but I'm having this [image: error]

My code:

```cpp
#include<enet/enet.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

ENetHost* client;
ENetAddress* address;
ENetPeer* peer;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int key;
    cout << "Hello";
    cin >> key;
    return 0;

    // initialize ENet

    if (enet_initialize() != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred while initializing ENet.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    atexit(enet_deinitialize);


}
```

Comment: Should your exact compile/link/include settings. It sounds like you just didn't actually link against it.

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, add "ws2_32.lib".

Comment: I added ws2_32.lib but still gives me the error